# ios dev UIPanGesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move an view. My problem is that the state ended, has a delay of 1 second.

It happens in the simulator. Is this normal? or I have a problem in my code?.

Thanks for all !

```
if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    float y = self.boxView.center.y;
    float move = 300;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^ {
                         self.boxView.center = CGPointMake(self.boxView.center.x, move);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it spends the last 1 second animating; you told it to. Try calling `self.boxView.center = CGPointMake(self.boxView.center.x, move);` without the `[UIView animateWithDuration...]`

Comment: The delay occurs when it detects the end event.

If I show a test message :

if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
NSLog(@"Test");
}

There is still a delay